# GNOME license not accepted issue when system has been rebooted

Tags: centos, software-installation, gnome, reboot, licenses

GNOME Desktop has been installed on CentOS7 using `sudo yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"` and when `startx` is executed the desktop starts. However, when the system reboots the following issue occurs:

[image]

When `c` has been executed the following occurs:

[image]

`1` results in:

[image]

and typing `2`

[image]

unchecks the box and the issue persists.

**Attempts to solve the issue**

According [this Q&A](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=49229), `1` should be executed to solve the issue, but that did not help.

**Questions**

1. Why does the issue occur once the system has been rebooted?
2. If it works to accept the license by issuing certain commands how to avoid that these commands need to be executed every time the system boots?
3. The last and main question is how to avoid that this accept license prompt appears at boot?

Comment: "According this Q&A, 1 should be executed to solve the issue, but that did not help." how didn't help? What message appeared when you pressed "1"?

Comment: @Braiam The question has been updated

Comment: Did you accepted the agreement (pressing 2)?

Comment: @Braiam the issue persists once 2 has been issued

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Concise**

1. Press `1`
2. Press `2` in order to change `[ ]` to `[x]` in front of `2) I accept the license agreement`
3. Press `q`
4. Accept license menu does not prompt anymore at boot

**Comprehensive**

The issue was caused because the prompt was not clear to me. First I thought that pressing `c` would result in continue, i.e., moving to section2, but that was not the case.

A Q&A was found that indicated that `1` should be pressed in order to continue to section 2 (see question).

Braiam asked whether `2` was pressed. Pressing `2` over and over again added an `X` and removed it once it was pressed again (see comments to question).

When the `X` was added, i.e. `[X] 2) I accept the license agreement.`, pressing `c` did not work, but `q` had to be chosen. My assumption was that an instruction would be displayed, e.g. `press a to accept`.

[image]

Once `yes` was entered the license was accepted. Every time the system reboots the `accept license menu` does not prompt anymore.

I still do not understand why the `license agreement menu` did not prompt during the installation of GNOME and this desktop could run without accepting any license agreement and the menu was prompted once the system had been rebooted, but the license is accepted now and answers this question.

Answer (score 4):

This issue annoyed the living daylights out of me earlier today since the update to the latest CentOS 7 release requires re-accepting the EULA, and the text interface for accepting the license is unintuitive to the point of being broken.

Simple fix to make this go away permanently:

1. Interrupt grub (press <kbd>e</kbd>)
2. Add `init=/bin/bash` to the end of your kernel line
3. When you get to the prompt, uninstall the initial-setup packages - do:

   ```
   rpm -e initial-setup initial-setup-gui
   ```
4. Reboot:

   ```
   sync;
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq; 
   echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
   ```